# Mongo bulk update not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkupdate

I'm trying to run a number of update operations on my MongoDB. I wanted to use the Bulk update operation specified  [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/), but this doesn't work for me, using pymongo. My code is as follows

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.test
bulk = db.testCol.initialize_unordered_bulk_op();
bulk.find({"_id":"1,1,1"}).update({"$set":{"attr1":1, "attr2":"X", "attr3":99}})
print bulk.execute()
```

The output of this is:

```
{'nModified': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 1, 'writeErrors': [], 'upserted': [], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nRemoved': 0, 'nInserted': 0}
```

From what I understand, Mongo is finding the document (nMatched=1), but not updating it (nModified=0). I can't figure out why it's doing this.

When I perform the operation manually, without the use of Bulk, the output seems to be correct and the record is modified as requested.
Code:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.test
print db.testCol.update({"_id":"1,1,1"}, {"attr1":1, "attr2":"X", "attr3":99})
```

This does work, both confirmed by the print and the contents of the database.

```
{'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. As far as I can tell I've followed the correct procedure for the execution of bulk updates.

Comment: If your existing document actually has the same values you are trying to `$set` then it is not an update. The new API recognizes this, where the legacy write concern response does not and reports the document as updated.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn! I think that was indeed the problem :)

Comment: Suggest @NeilLunn posts his answer as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I created a utility function that does bulk updates.

```
def bulk_update(db, collection_name, update_set_where_list):
    """

    :param db: pymongo.database.Database Object
    :param collection_name: Collection name
    :param update_set_where_list:
    :return: full result dictionary
    """
    required_keys = ["where", "set"]
    bulk = db[collection_name].initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

    for update_where_set in update_set_where_list:
        if all(key in update_where_set for key in required_keys):
             bulk.find(update_where_set["where"]).update({"$set": update_where_set["set"]})
        else:
            raise Exception("Required key missing. {}".format(required_keys))

    return bulk.execute()
```

For example, consider that `myCollection` collection in `test` database needs to be updated with y = 3 where x = 1, and y = 6 where x = 5.

Then call to the utility function looks like

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['test']
update_set_where_list = [{"where":{"x":1},"set":{"y":3}},{"where":{"x":5},"set":{"y":6}}]
bulk_update(db=db, collection_name="myCollection", update_set_where_list=update_set_where_list)
```